# Why do we urinate more often in winter compaired to summer?

Tags: human-biology, human-physiology, osmoregulation

I have been thinking of this question for a long time, but I do not seem to find an answer yet. Is there a hormonal change in our body during winter due to which we have to run to toilet often?

Comment: Is this really the case and not just observation bias? It is possibly that it is connected to more sweating in the summer - the body produces higher concentrated urine then to save water.

Comment: Is this a well-known phenomenon that and general to others? As in, is there evidence for this pattern?

Comment: I posted my answer @user28194. Hope you find it useful :)

Comment: Who exactly is 'we' here?  I don't, at least to any noticable degree, though I admit to not keeping detailed records of frequency/volume.

Comment: Istead of counting your volume why dont you answer the Q. I had asked the Q.because it is generally seen in many people. You may be an exception case but a lot of people are having this probem.

Comment: It's a problem? Seems like a solution.

Comment: @user28194 If "a lot of people are having this probem [sic]", then surely you can find a scientific citation for this phenomenon? Saying that "it is generally seen in many people" is not proof, it is anecdotal evidence at best. Also, you would do well to stop insulting people and demanding answers. You don't have a *right* to have your question answered. We are all volunteers here, and answer if and when we feel like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no 100 % sure answer for this as, obviously, nobody is that much interested in studying about urination. But there are some theories, of which the most popular and accepted one is [cold diuresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diuresis#Cold-induced_diuresis).

> Cold-induced diuresis, or cold diuresis, is a phenomenon that occurs in humans after exposure to a hypothermic environment, usually during mild to moderate hypothermia.

According to this theory, what exactly happens is this (I'll explain in steps for better understanding):

- When your body senses cold or low temperature of environment, it constricts the blood vessels near your skin and external organs and restricts your blood to the inner core of your body to maintain its temperature.
- Thus, it causes the blood pressure to increase as there is same amount of blood in lesser volume.
- This induces negative feedback on [ADH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasopressin) (a vasoconstrictor) i.e. its secretion is reduced.
- Now when blood vessels in kidney get proper amount of blood (as blood vessels aren't constricted now), they sense high blood pressure and try to reduce it as soon as possible.
- So they transfer more amount of water from blood to bladder which fills the bladder more quickly and causes an urge to urinate.
- Thus, we urinate more in colder climate.

There are some more theories related to it too, but they aren't as popular. According to another theory, when we are exposed to cold weather, [aquaporins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquaporin) are inhibited around the body, making it impossible for water to be taken in by cells, leaving a lot more of it in the blood. Again, the body will try to balance that pressure, pulling water from the blood and storing it in the bladder. You can get a more frank and interactive explanation [here](https://www.scienceabc.com/humans/why-do-we-urinate-more-when-were-cold.html).

Comment: So i am not wrong completely...ADH is responsible.

Comment: Yeah it is responsible, but not how you thought it to be ;)

Comment: ADH is not secreted by the kidneys, it *acts* on kidneys. It's secreted by the neurohypophysis.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado yeah right, but I said so as its secretion is induced from kidneys. I'll correct that, thx.

Answer (score -3):

I think that due to cold temperature the hormone ADH cannot function well. As in low temperature the enzymes becomes less active. So as the ADH hormone is not working well the suger concentration will increase in our blood due to which more amount of water will transfer from our cell to the blood stream. And this excess water will be removed by the kidney and result in polyurea.

Comment: First: What is ADH? Then: Although enzymes do have a lower productivity when it is colder, this plays no role here. The outside temperature does not influence your body temperature (at least mostly) so this does not play a role.

Comment: ADH is the antideuratichormone or anti diabetic hormone.

Comment: It would be good to edit your answer, so people who are not familiar with the topic can understand this.

Comment: Well its anti-diuretic hormone (i.e. unrelated to sugar control) if that wasn't a typo error. The reason is actually different, I'll post an answer soon.

Comment: Ok..i am looking forword to you answer.@another'Homo sapien'